# How can I make a JS function wait to execute?

Tags: javascript, html

I'am pretty new to programming, and wanted to make a clicker-game with JS and HTML. Now I want to add achievements. They should pop up, and be displayed for a couple of (5 maybe?) seconds, then fade away.

I have a solution so far, but the function will run every 10sec. and if you should get the achievement after the 6th. second, the pop-up will be displayed for maybe 2 - 4 seconds, before fading away.

Briefly, when completed the achievement, the achievement (div) should pop-up, stay there for 5 seconds, then fade away.

Here is my JS:

```
//Check if achievement #1 is completed / true:
if(Ach1up == true){
    Modal1stAch.style.display = "block";
    Ach1up = null;
}

//Fade-out function
setTimeout(function () {
    Modal1stAch.style.opacity = "0.0";
    Modal1stAch.style.WebkitTransition = "2s";    
    Modal1stAch.style.transition = "2s";
}, 10000);
```

Comment: Could you please provide information on when the delay should start. If you wish to have a javascript function delay on page load, you can try adding the script to the bottom of the page inside a function and then call that function using something like `<body onload="myfunction();">`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understood right, what you need is to grab your fadeout code into a function and call it 5s after the ach1up is true.

```
//Check if achievement #1 is completed / true:
if(Ach1up == true){
    Modal1stAch.style.display = "block";
    Ach1up = null;
    setTimeout(function () { //wait 5 seconds to fade the popup
       popupFadeOut();
    }, 5000);
}

//Fade-out function 
// you write it, and wait to be called.
function popupFadeOut() {
    Modal1stAch.style.opacity = "0.0";
    Modal1stAch.style.WebkitTransition = "2s";    
    Modal1stAch.style.transition = "2s";
}
```

Comment: Wow, thanks. Haha, that was it! :) Exactly what I wanted